# PdfMake Displaying Dynamic data with styling

Tags: javascript, css, html, pdfmake

I am using PdfMake to generate a pdf on the client side. I store a list of skills in an array like so:

```
var skills: ["hiking", "running", "typing", "etc"];
```

I am trying to show this array of skills like this similar to stack overflow  (**with styling such as border radius and background color etc**):

[image]

PdfMake does not provide any functions that I know of which will allow me to do this. Does anyone know how I can display an array of data with styling as tags using pdf make?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```js
var skills = ["hiking", "running", "typing", "etc"];
for (i=0; i<skills.length; i++) {
  document.write("<a class='tag'>"+skills[i]+"</a>");
}
```

```css
a.tag {
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  }
```